# Find locations with leaflet and search control from api

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to get the city location of my stores in leaflet.

```
[{"loc":["38.3911543","42.3116525"],"title":"Ankis Gardin Atelj\u00e9","city":"Norway"}]
```

What I'm trying to do is find locations and stores from API.
I don't really know how to get this to work. But iknow that i need to run a function like this.

```
function('Norway');
```

This is my code right know.. If i hit "MY_API_CITY" I want it to show up. Some one how know what I'm trying to do?

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(63, 15), zoom: 5});
      var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
      map.addLayer(googleLayer);
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
//var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({layer: markers, initial: false});
//map.addControl(controlSearch);
L.control.search({
    wrapper: 'searchbox',
    url: 'API_URL',
    text: 'Storename',
    value: 'Find'
}).addTo(map);


function locateUser() {
    this.map.locate({setView : true, maxZoom: 16});
}

$.getJSON("MY_API_URL", function (json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.result.length; i++) {
        //markers.addLayer(new L.Marker([json.result[i].lat, json.result[i].lng]));
        var title = "<p class='lead' style='margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;font-family: sans-serif !important;'><a target='_blank' href='http://blablabla/bla/"+ json.result[i].uri +"'>" + json.result[i].title + "</a></p><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i> " + json.result[i].adress, //value searched
            city = json.result[i].city,
            loc = [json.result[i].lat, json.result[i].lng], //position found
            marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng([json.result[i].lat, json.result[i].lng]), {
                                title: title,
            });
        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
});

markers.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["38.3911543","42.3116525"]
```

Places in the world are represented by coordinates that should be numbers, not strings, like they are here. This problem lies in your API incorrectly encoding its output.